# Not able to compare Object Id using handlebars?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

This is my first time using Handlebars. I am trying to compare user _id with logged in user id. I am saving data in MongoDB using mongoose. I found a helper from StackOverflow but it doesn't seem to compare value. The schema for user and Tracker and code I am using is below.

```
var trackerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please add an description']
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    }
});
mongoose.model('Tracker', trackerSchema);

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }

});
const User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Helper function in **app.js** file

```
const hbs = exphb.create({
    extname: 'hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'mainLayout',
    layoutDir: __dirname + 'views/layouts/',
    partialsDir: __dirname + '/views/partials/',

    helpers: {
        ifEqual: function (v1, v2, options) {
            if (v1 != v2) {
                return options.inverse(this);
            }
            return options.fn(this);
        },
    }
})
```

Using helper function **ifEqual** in handlebar file

```
{{#each list}}
<td>{{this.createdAt}}</td>
<td>{{this.user}}</td> //i am seeing this.user for example - **5ef9fb54f4bb8dff810104f7**    
<td>
    {{#ifEqual this.user looged_user_id }} //looged_user_id coming from req.user._id.toString()
    <a href="/tracker/{{this._id}}"> Edit </a>
    <a href="/tracker/delete/{{this._id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete
    </a>
    {{else}}
    <a href="#"> Edit </a>
    <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete
    </a>
    {{/ifEqual}}
</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Please guide how can I compare two _ids.

Comment: I believe you cannot pass a javascript variable ``looged_user_id`` like you are trying to in an hbs helper function. Do a ``console.log(v1, v2)`` inside your helper function to validate.

Comment: @RaviKukreja yes you right. I see undefined in logs. How can I do that then? looged_user_id is coming from req.user using passport sessions. Thanks

Comment: Is this an express app? If yes you must be calling ``res.render("path to your hbs file")``from your route handler. Could you post that part of the code?

Comment: @RaviKukreja I am already doing this ```res.render("tracker/list", {list: body, isEps: req.user.isEps, looged_user_id: req.user._id.toString()});```

Comment: Try sending looged_user_id like ``looged_user_id: new hbs.SafeString(JSON.stringify(req.user._id.toString()))``

Comment: @RaviKukreja I am not sure how to use this in Track routes. I can add in app.js as helper ```toString: function (arg1) {return new hbs.SafeString(JSON.stringify(arg1.toString()));}``` but then i dont know how i can use this in hbs - may be something like ```{{#ifEqual this.user toString looged_user_id }}```

Comment: Why can't you can add it in the same file as your route handler? Instead of ``looged_user_id: req.user._id.toString()`` you have to write  ``looged_user_id: new hbs.SafeString(JSON.stringify(req.user._id.toString()))`` and require hbs in the page if it does not exist already ``const hbs = require("hbs")``

Comment: @RaviKukreja I tried but still v2 is undefined when I console.log(v1, v2). Cant think of anything now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218376/discussion-between-ravi-kukreja-and-user557657).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were missing two things:

1. Sending looged_user_id to your hbs:

   `res.render("tracker/list", { list: body,  logged_user_id: req.user._id, });`
2. Accessing logged_user_id it the right way inside the #each handlebar loop. When inside the loop you cannot directly use the data passed. You have to provide the right path to logged_user_id which in your case would be ../logged_user_id.

The ../ path segment references the parent template scope using which you can access logged_user_id.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you need to pass your looged_user_id to template first, then only it will get in your helper function.

try this on http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/

**Template:**

```
    {{#each list}}
    <td>{{this.createdAt}}</td>
    <td>{{this.user}}</td> 
    <td>
        {{#ifCond this.user}} //Here 1 is just hardcoded insted of that need to change with actal variable
        <a href="/tracker/{{this._id}}"> Edit for if </a>
        <a href="/tracker/delete/{{this._id}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete looged_user_id
        </a>
        {{else}}
        <a href="#"> Edit for else </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete
        </a>
        {{/ifCond}}
    </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
```

**Context:**

```
    {
        "list": [{
            "user": 1,
            "content": "hello"
        },{
            "user": 2,
            "content": "world"
        }],
    }
```

**Register Helper function:**

```
    Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, options) {
      if(v1 === looged_user_id ) {
        return options.fn(this);
      }
      return options.inverse(this);
    });
```

**Result:**

```
    <td></td>
    <td>1</td> 
    <td>
        <a href="/tracker/"> Edit for if </a>
        <a href="/tracker/delete/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete looged_user_id
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>2</td> 
    <td>
        <a href="#"> Edit for else </a>
        <a href="#" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?');"> Delete
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I am passing in template as javascript variable - looged_user_id but handlebars doesnt like it.

Comment: @user557657 Ok, Then you can simply replace that v2 to looged_user_id in your helper function(if your not having more than one looged_user_id at a time) and remove v2 from helper function parameter and from template

Comment: Sorry I am not following you. is possible you can edit you answer?

Comment: In my helper function v1 is this.user and v2 is looged_user_id

Comment: How this going to work? looged_user_id is not defined in anywhere in Helper function? it is error out ```ReferenceError: looged_user_id is not defined``` And in my case i am creating helper function in my app.js. I dont know how to use ```Handlebars.registerHelper``` Do I need to install Handlebars npm?